# How to configure Commons VFS to automatically detect gz files

Tags: java, apache-commons-vfs

Our application is using [Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/) to read various types of files. We use the automatic file type detection VFS provides, via its [file extension mapping](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/api.html#Configuration_File).

The problem: VFS misclassifies gz files (ie. files whose name ends in `.gz`) as regular files, rather than as GZIP files. This prevents us from using VFS to read the (decompressed) content of gz files, without some special-case manually hack-arounding.

I've traced the problem to `org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.FileContentInfoFilenameFactory.create()`, which calls

```
FileNameMap fileNameMap = URLConnection.getFileNameMap();
contentType = fileNameMap.getContentTypeFor(name);
```

This loads the file `content-types.properties` from the current Java installation. This file (on Windows, at least) contains this mapping:

```
application/octet-stream: \
    description=Generic Binary Stream;\
    file_extensions=.saveme,.dump,.hqx,.arc,.obj,.lib,.bin,.exe,.zip,.gz
```

According to the source code, `org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.FileTypeMap` allows this mapping to take precedence over the file extension map with which VFS was configured.

Can anyone think of a way of either (a) extending a class or two of VFS to work around this problem or (b) configuring VFS and/or Java itself so that VFS correctly classifies gz files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class like the following, to override the `getContentTypeFor` method of `FileNameMap` and exclude the troublesome `application/octet-stream` entry:

```
public static class MyFileNameMap implements FileNameMap
{
    private FileNameMap delegate = URLConnection.getFileNameMap();

    @Override
    public String getContentTypeFor( String fileName )
    {
        String contentType = delegate.getContentTypeFor( fileName );
        if( "application/octet-stream".equals( contentType ) )
        {
            // Sun's java classifies zip and gzip as application/octet-stream,
            // which VFS then uses, instead of looking at its extension
            // map for a more specific mime type
            return null;
        }
        return contentType;
    }
}
```

Install this new class via:

```
URLConnection.setFileNameMap( new MyFileNameMap() );
```

Now when you call `FileSystemManager.resolveFile()`, VFS will choose the correct file type for `gz` files by falling back to its extensions map.

**Note:** This is a global change to the current JVM, so be careful if you are using any other code that needs this mime type entry for things like `.exe` files.